# Hibernate: how can I delete an entity in the one-to-many relationship in the "many" side from the "one" side

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have noticed that Hibernate does not allow to delete an entity in an one-to-many relationship.
I have two tables (and entities), company and employee.
I would like to delete an employee with the code below:

```
..
company.getEmployees().remove(myEmployee); //employees is a collection in Company, it is  mapped as a one-to-many relationship (@OneToMany)
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(company);
```

Do you have any idea how can I force a delete? or at least get an Exception?

Comment: Show us the two entities and their mapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, by default is not removed. But you can map the `@OneToMany` relation with a [orphanRemoval = true attribute](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch11.html#example-one-to-many-with-orphan-removal) in order to be automatically removed:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true) 
public Set<Employee> getEmployees() { return employees; }
```

Comment: thanks, and what about if want to set the foreign key in employee to null?

Comment: You can't do it transitively with `cascades`. Just do it manually by removing the employee from the collection and setting the company to null in the employee. You can create a special method for this on the company if you need it multiple times.